# Interpreting density scale geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question on how the values are calculated for geom_density:
here is a code to reproduce my results:

```r
    a <- structure(c(1.94603297055443, NA, 0.543010708224088, -0.694950111479158, 
    1.12072575741894, 0.955664314791837, 0.543010708224088, NA, -1.76784948855531, 
    1.20325647873249, NA, -1.43772660330111, 1.03819503610539, NA, 
    0.0478263803427896, 0.0478263803427896, 1.78097152792733, 1.20325647873249, 
    -0.28229650491141, NA, -1.27266516067401, NA, NA, 0.873133593478287, 
    NA, -1.52025732461466, 0.625541429537638, 0.955664314791837, 
    NA, 0.873133593478287, -2.51062598037725, 1.20325647873249, 1.03819503610539, 
    -0.28229650491141, -1.76784948855531, NA, 0.130357101656339, 
    0.543010708224088, NA, 0.295418544283439, NA, -0.28229650491141, 
    -0.612419390165609, -1.02507299673336, 0.625541429537638, -0.364827226224959, 
    -2.01544165249595, 1.20325647873249, NA, 0.460479986910538, 0.295418544283439, 
    NA, 1.94603297055443, 1.78097152792733, -0.777480832792708, 0.955664314791837, 
    NA, -0.860011554106258, 1.12072575741894, 0.295418544283439, 
    0.212887822969889, NA, -0.612419390165609, 0.790602872164737, 
    NA, 0.212887822969889, -0.447357947538509, 1.36831792135959, 
    -0.19976578359786, 1.94603297055443, NA, -0.942542275419808, 
    NA, -1.19013443936046, 1.86350224924088, -1.52025732461466, 1.94603297055443, 
    NA, 0.460479986910538, 0.625541429537638, -0.364827226224959, 
    0.130357101656339, 1.94603297055443, -1.02507299673336, -0.612419390165609, 
    -0.28229650491141, -0.942542275419808, -1.52025732461466, -0.28229650491141, 
    NA, NA, NA, -0.447357947538509, NA, 0.460479986910538, 0.873133593478287, 
    -0.529888668852059, 1.12072575741894, 0.0478263803427896, -1.85038020986886, 
    0.873133593478287, 0.130357101656339, 0.955664314791837, 0.130357101656339, 
    -0.860011554106258, 0.790602872164737, -0.19976578359786, -0.0347043409707605, 
    -1.35519588198756, NA, -0.11723506228431, NA, 0.708072150851187, 
    0.955664314791837, 0.377949265596989, NA, NA, -0.364827226224959, 
    -1.52025732461466, -0.11723506228431, 1.94603297055443, -0.777480832792708, 
    1.03819503610539, NA, 0.460479986910538, -0.11723506228431, 0.625541429537638, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.130357101656339, -1.93291093118241, NA, 0.212887822969889, 
    -0.777480832792708, NA, 0.708072150851187, NA, NA, 0.873133593478287, 
    NA, 1.94603297055443, -1.43772660330111, NA, 0.873133593478287, 
    0.377949265596989, -0.860011554106258, 0.130357101656339, -0.19976578359786, 
    -0.28229650491141, 0.625541429537638, NA, NA, NA, 1.03819503610539, 
    -0.364827226224959, -0.28229650491141, NA, -0.694950111479158, 
    -1.76784948855531, -0.19976578359786, 1.53337936398669, 0.460479986910538, 
    -0.0347043409707605, 0.295418544283439, -0.0347043409707605, 
    1.36831792135959, 0.212887822969889, NA, -2.51062598037725, NA, 
    0.0478263803427896, 0.625541429537638, NA, -0.364827226224959, 
    -0.0347043409707605, 1.03819503610539, -2.4280952590637, 0.0478263803427896, 
    -0.942542275419808, -0.612419390165609, 0.460479986910538, 1.20325647873249, 
    NA, 0.708072150851187, 0.377949265596989, NA, NA, 1.12072575741894, 
    -1.60278804592821, -0.0347043409707605, NA, NA, 0.460479986910538, 
    1.20325647873249, 0.377949265596989, 0.377949265596989, NA, -1.43772660330111, 
    1.45084864267314, 0.955664314791837, -1.68531876724176, 0.625541429537638, 
    NA, -1.76784948855531, 0.0478263803427896, 1.94603297055443, 
    1.69844080661379, NA, 0.625541429537638, 0.873133593478287, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -2.0979723738095, 0.295418544283439, 1.94603297055443, 
    0.625541429537638, 1.20325647873249, -1.35519588198756, -0.364827226224959, 
    NA, 0.0478263803427896, 0.543010708224088, -0.364827226224959, 
    0.955664314791837, -0.19976578359786, -1.27266516067401, -0.28229650491141, 
    0.708072150851187, 1.86350224924088, NA, -0.19976578359786, -0.529888668852059, 
    0.130357101656339, NA, NA, 1.78097152792733, NA, -0.28229650491141, 
    -1.68531876724176, NA, 0.295418544283439, -0.942542275419808, 
    NA, 1.12072575741894, 0.460479986910538, 0.460479986910538, 0.377949265596989, 
    0.460479986910538, NA, -2.2630338164366, -0.860011554106258, 
    0.955664314791837, NA, NA, NA, -2.34556453775015, -0.529888668852059, 
    -0.0347043409707605, NA, NA, NA, 1.12072575741894, 0.955664314791837, 
    NA, -0.529888668852059, -0.11723506228431, 0.790602872164737, 
    NA, -1.19013443936046, 0.0478263803427896, NA, 0.460479986910538, 
    NA, 0.377949265596989, NA, -1.10760371804691, 1.20325647873249, 
    NA, 1.03819503610539, 1.20325647873249, 0.543010708224088, 1.03819503610539, 
    NA, -2.51062598037725, 0.460479986910538, -0.19976578359786, 
    -2.0979723738095, -0.529888668852059, -1.02507299673336, 1.20325647873249, 
    -1.60278804592821, NA, -2.34556453775015, 1.20325647873249, NA, 
    -0.942542275419808, 1.36831792135959, 0.295418544283439, -0.612419390165609, 
    1.03819503610539, NA, -0.364827226224959, 0.295418544283439, 
    -0.28229650491141, 0.790602872164737, NA, NA, -0.860011554106258, 
    0.0478263803427896, 1.20325647873249, 1.03819503610539, NA, -0.0347043409707605, 
    0.625541429537638, 0.625541429537638, -0.942542275419808, -2.01544165249595, 
    0.955664314791837, -1.27266516067401, -0.777480832792708, -0.19976578359786, 
    -0.28229650491141, NA, -0.447357947538509, -1.02507299673336, 
    -0.529888668852059, 0.212887822969889, 0.212887822969889, -0.364827226224959, 
    -1.43772660330111, NA, NA, NA, 0.873133593478287, -0.447357947538509, 
    0.0478263803427896, NA, 1.03819503610539, 1.20325647873249, -1.02507299673336, 
    -0.364827226224959, -2.51062598037725, -0.777480832792708, 0.790602872164737, 
    0.625541429537638, 0.790602872164737, 0.0478263803427896, -0.28229650491141, 
    -0.0347043409707605, 0.543010708224088, -0.777480832792708, -1.35519588198756, 
    NA, 0.625541429537638, -0.694950111479158, -0.860011554106258, 
    1.03819503610539, -0.11723506228431, -0.28229650491141, -0.612419390165609, 
    NA, -0.447357947538509, NA, NA, 0.708072150851187, 1.20325647873249, 
    -0.11723506228431, 0.708072150851187, -1.68531876724176, -0.777480832792708, 
    -0.28229650491141, -2.51062598037725, NA, 0.708072150851187, 
    NA, -0.942542275419808, -0.447357947538509, 0.873133593478287, 
    1.03819503610539, -2.51062598037725, 0.955664314791837, -0.529888668852059, 
    -1.43772660330111, -1.27266516067401, 0.295418544283439, NA, 
    -0.28229650491141, NA, 1.69844080661379, 0.625541429537638, -0.19976578359786, 
    -0.447357947538509, NA, -1.93291093118241, NA, 0.543010708224088, 
    NA, NA, -0.694950111479158, -0.942542275419808, 0.873133593478287, 
    -0.19976578359786, -0.447357947538509, -0.19976578359786, -0.364827226224959, 
    NA, 0.625541429537638, 0.625541429537638, NA, 0.708072150851187, 
    0.377949265596989, -1.68531876724176, 1.03819503610539, NA, NA, 
    0.0478263803427896, -0.28229650491141, 0.625541429537638, -0.364827226224959, 
    0.377949265596989, -0.19976578359786, -1.85038020986886, NA, 
    0.130357101656339, 0.130357101656339, 1.69844080661379, NA, -0.942542275419808, 
    0.212887822969889, -0.11723506228431, 0.0478263803427896, -0.28229650491141, 
    NA, 1.20325647873249, -1.76784948855531, 0.460479986910538, 0.708072150851187, 
    NA, 1.45084864267314, 1.03819503610539, -0.28229650491141, 1.69844080661379, 
    0.460479986910538, -2.0979723738095, -2.51062598037725, NA, -1.10760371804691, 
    0.955664314791837, NA, -0.28229650491141, 0.543010708224088, 
    0.543010708224088, NA, -0.694950111479158, -1.76784948855531, 
    -0.447357947538509, 0.295418544283439, 1.12072575741894, -0.612419390165609, 
    NA, -1.52025732461466, 0.377949265596989, NA, NA, -0.529888668852059, 
    NA, -0.942542275419808, -1.02507299673336, NA, 0.460479986910538, 
    NA, 0.955664314791837, NA, -1.35519588198756, -1.68531876724176, 
    NA, 1.20325647873249, -0.19976578359786, NA, NA, 0.212887822969889, 
    NA, -1.52025732461466, NA, 0.790602872164737, NA, -1.52025732461466, 
    1.03819503610539, 1.20325647873249, NA, NA, 0.212887822969889, 
    0.295418544283439, NA, 1.94603297055443, 0.130357101656339, NA, 
    1.94603297055443, -0.364827226224959, -0.0347043409707605, 1.12072575741894, 
    -0.612419390165609, NA, -0.447357947538509, -0.28229650491141, 
    NA, -0.447357947538509, 0.873133593478287, 0.873133593478287, 
    0.460479986910538, 0.0478263803427896, -0.694950111479158, -2.01544165249595, 
    -1.60278804592821, -0.364827226224959, 0.955664314791837, -1.68531876724176, 
    -0.28229650491141, 0.708072150851187, 0.377949265596989, NA, 
    -0.19976578359786, 0.460479986910538, 0.212887822969889, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.212887822969889, -1.27266516067401, 0.295418544283439, 
    0.543010708224088, 0.460479986910538, 0.625541429537638, 0.377949265596989, 
    1.03819503610539, -0.777480832792708, 0.130357101656339, -0.529888668852059, 
    -0.529888668852059, 0.460479986910538, 0.460479986910538, NA, 
    0.460479986910538, 1.28578720004604, -0.28229650491141, 0.212887822969889, 
    0.212887822969889, -0.777480832792708, 0.955664314791837, NA, 
    -0.28229650491141, NA, -1.19013443936046, NA, 0.790602872164737, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1.86350224924088, 0.212887822969889, -1.43772660330111, 
    0.130357101656339, 0.212887822969889, 1.69844080661379, -2.01544165249595, 
    0.873133593478287, 1.61591008530023, -1.35519588198756, NA, 0.460479986910538, 
    -0.19976578359786, 0.543010708224088, -0.860011554106258, -0.28229650491141, 
    0.873133593478287, NA, 0.873133593478287, -0.364827226224959, 
    NA, -0.529888668852059, NA, 0.212887822969889, -1.27266516067401, 
    0.543010708224088, -0.28229650491141, 0.543010708224088, -1.19013443936046, 
    -1.76784948855531, NA, NA, 0.130357101656339, -0.447357947538509, 
    0.0478263803427896, -1.43772660330111, 0.295418544283439, -0.860011554106258, 
    NA, 1.03819503610539, -0.860011554106258, NA, NA, 0.543010708224088, 
    -0.0347043409707605, -0.0347043409707605, NA, 0.625541429537638, 
    0.0478263803427896, -1.02507299673336, NA), .Dim = c(614L, 1L
    ))
    a= data.frame(a=a)
    ggplot(a, aes(x=a)) + 
      geom_density()
```

[image]

However, when I calculate proportions, my values are way smaller

```
    table(a$a) %>% data.frame() %>%  mutate(freq= Freq/459)%>% arrange(desc(freq))
```

So what is exactly plotted as density?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question as such. Maybe check out [the wikipedia page on probability density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)?

Comment: The `geom_density()` layer calculates something called a Kernel Density Estimate (KDE). You can interpret this as a continuous histogram. Briefly and by default, a small normal density curve is centered at every datapoint and then the densities are summed for all datapoints in a group. This is then normalized to integrate to 1 to generate the KDE.

Comment: thank you  @teunbrand, so if I have to plots : one has max kernel density on the plot  0.4 ( as I showed on a graph) and lets say another graph has Kernel density with is 0.04 ( 10 times smaller). What can cause such a difference?

Comment: The range of the data matters, if you have data between -1 < x < 1, density values are going to be higher then when the data is between -1000 < x < 1000. This is due to the property that it should integrate to 1: if the range is larger, the values are going to be smaller.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an eleboration of what is mentioned in the comments, to show it slightly more visually.

Just like histograms have a bin width, KDEs have a bandwidth. For the default gaussian kernel, that is the standard deviation parameter of the normal density function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

# Pick some data
data <- faithful$eruptions

bandwidth <- 0.5

# Get data range
range <- range(data)

# Setup a sequence of x-coordinates
x_coord <- seq(range[1] - bandwidth, range[2] + bandwidth, length.out = 512)
```

Now we can calculate for every datapoint the normal density function, where `mu` is the datapoint value and the standard deviation is the bandwidth.  What I'm doing below is just calculating these bell-curves for every datapoint.

```
# Calculate individual densities
indi_dens <- vapply(data, function(mu) {
  dnorm(x_coord, mu, sd = bandwidth)
}, x_coord)

# Plot individual densities
indi_data <- reshape2::melt(indi_dens)
indi_data$Var1 <- x_coord[indi_data$Var1]

ggplot(indi_data) +
  geom_line(aes(Var1, value, group = Var2))
```

[image]

The next step is simply summing up all the individual densities for every x-coordinate. We divide this by the number of observations, such that the area of the resulting KDE is equal to 1.

I'll show our calculated densities in blue, and the `geom_density()` of the same data in red.

```r
# Sum density for every x-coordinate
summed_dens <- rowSums(indi_dens)
# Make it integrate to 1 by dividing by the number of observations
summed_dens <- summed_dens / length(data)

# Prepare plotting data
plotdata <- data.frame(
  x = x_coord,
  y = summed_dens
)

ggplot(plotdata) +
  geom_line(aes(x, y), colour = "blue", size = 2) +
  # Overlay density calculated by geom_density() for the same data
  geom_density(data = faithful, aes(x = eruptions),
               bw = bandwidth, color = "red", linetype = 2, size = 2)
```

[image]

You can see that they come pretty close. To elaborate a bit further, because KDEs are integrating to one, meaning that the total area under the curve must be 1, the density is going to be lower for data that spans a wider range and higher for data that spans a lower range. This is not only true for KDE but pretty much any density. Compare for example the normal density curves for normal distributions with `sd = 1` and `sd = 5`, the latter has a wider range than the former.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(sd = 1), colour = "blue") +
  geom_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(sd = 5), colour = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-10, 10)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "density")
```

[image]